# Django - How do I display only the questions with choices?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am completing the official Django tutorial. The tutorial involves creating a polls app, which consists of creating questions with choices.

Currently, the index page shows one question instance for each choice that the question has. For example, if the question is 'what is your favourite thing to eat?' and that question's choices are 'Cabbage', 'Metal', and 'My pride', the index page shows three repetitions of 'what is your favourite thing to eat?'.

I am trying to alter the index page to display only one instance of each question that has choices. How must I change what I have written already?

*views.py*

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_questions'

    def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Return the last ten published questions. Exclude questions to be
    published in the future and questions that have no choices.
    """
    published_questions_with_choices = Question.objects.filter(
        choice__isnull=False).filter(
        pub_date__lte=timezone.now())

    return published_questions_with_choices.order_by('-pub_date')[:10]
```

*index.html*

```
    {% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">

{% if latest_questions %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_questions %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

*models.py*

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

The loaded index screen (including a free image from unsplash as background):

[image]

I suspect that I must alter the `{% for question in latest_questions %}` in views.py. However, I am unsure how it must be changed.

Thank you very much for any response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering on m2m relationships will return the origin model multiple times if there are multiple related objects that fulfil the filter. You should add `distinct()` to your query:

```
published_questions_with_choices = Question.objects.filter(
    choice__isnull=False).filter(
    pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).distinct()
```

You'll see in your template that the question is shown only once.